# How to upload Files in Spring Controller Using @RequestBody?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring boot using Angular. 
I am trying to upload multiple file in a single request along with other attributes.

E.g. I have a Product and inside that I have variant product. both have gallery images.

I am submitting Base product which contains variant as well.

here is sample object in the controller side which is submitted.

```
   public class ProductDTO {
     private String name;
     private String code;
     private String size;
     private List<MultipartFile> multimedias;
     private List<ProductDTO> variants;
   }
```

Controller code is below ;

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseDTO<ProductDTO> createProduct(@RequestBody ProductDTO productDTO, Authentication authentication, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return tryCreateItem(() -> {
            productService.createOrUpdateProduct(productDTO, true);
            return productDTO;
        }, response);
    }
```

In angular side the Product and Variants along with the gallery images is submitted. 
But I am not getting the files in the Controller.

Can anyone please help me out with my scenario.

**How to upload the files inside the Form as RequestBody object ?**

I am tagging Angularjs hoping anyone may come across with this scenario or any specific config is required in angular side.

Comment: did you check https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ ?

Comment: yes @Aboullaite already gone through so many articles like this. No where I found the File sent in a Form in Rest controller. With Request Param is fine but that is not fit for my Requirement. I can not get the files based on different objects

Comment: The question is tagged as AngularJS but there is no AngularJS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseDTO<ProductDTO> createProduct(@RequestBody ProductDTO productDTO, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, Authentication authentication, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
if(null!=files){
for(int i=0;i<files.length();i++){
 multimedias.add(files[0]);
} 
}
    return tryCreateItem(() -> {
        productService.createOrUpdateProduct(productDTO, true);
        return productDTO;
    }, response);
}
public class ProductDTO {
 private String name;
 private String code;
 private String size;
 @transient 
 private List<MultipartFile> multimedias=new ArrayList<MultipartFile>();
 private List<ProductDTO> variants;
```

}